# Firebase AngularJS array map()

Tags: angularjs, arrays, firebase, dictionary, ionic-framework

I have multiple firebase items that I am looping through and they have name, categoryId, lat, lon.

I am trying to calculate a distance from 2 lat,lon (one is the one in firebase), the other is the user's location.

All of this is fine, and I can calculate it fine too. However, how do I inject/map the new variable into the firebase array that I am subscribed to?

```
this.categoryId = this.navParams.get('categoryId');
afoDatabase.list('/list', {query: {
    orderByChild: "categoryId",
    equalTo:  parseInt(this.categoryId)
}}).subscribe(listItems => {
    this.items = listItems; //need to add distance within array
    loadingPopup.dismiss().catch(() => {});
});
```

For example, I have a variable called distance, that calculates everything and has the value. How do I add it in the this?items - so I can call it from the HTML side?

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

To inject, first create a function and create a variable (e.g. this.distance) and get the value of your function on this variable. After that use a for loop to increment, based on length - and use `this.items[i]["distance"]` to add to each one. For example:

```
this.categoryId = this.navParams.get('categoryId');
  afoDatabase.list('/list', {query: {
      orderByChild: "categoryId",
      equalTo:  parseInt(this.categoryId)
  }}).subscribe(listItems => {
        this.items = listItems;

        this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({timeout:15000}).then((resp) => {

         this.myLat = resp.coords.latitude;
         this.myLong = resp.coords.longitude;


        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log('Error getting location', error);
        });



        for (var i = 0, len = this.items.length; i < len; i++) {
            this.distance = this.calculateDistance(this.myLat, this.myLong, this.items[i].lat, this.items[i].lng);
            this.items[i]["distance"] = Math.round(this.distance);
              console.log('testing myLat', this.myLat)
              console.log('testing myLong', this.myLong)
          }

          console.log('testing inject', this.items)
        loadingPopup.dismiss().catch(() => {});
  });
```

Function

```
calculateDistance(lat1:number,lon1:number,lat2:number,lon2:number){

  let R = 6371; // km
  let dLat = (lat2 - lat1) * Math.PI / 180;
  let dLon = (lon2 - lon1) * Math.PI / 180;
  let a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
                  Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI / 180) *
                  Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
  let c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
  let d = R * c;
    return d;
}
```